# Why won't my thumbnails show in nautilus when viewing from a USB device?

Tags: nautilus, 22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, but this happens with all operating systems that use nautilus, including Fedora:

[image: 1]

I have tried using dconf editor and upped the cache to 150MB, but no changes.

Comment: Perfectly normal when using the list view.

Comment: 1.) You appear to have the correct setting corresponding to your intent: "Show thumbnails: All files" 2.) I believe Nautilus does not show image previews when in list view, even if those exist in cache (as in your screenshot). 3.) I can imagine that the image preview generating script kicks in only when you first switch to the "thumbnails" / "grid" view mode.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu desktop v22.04 simply click on the first icon in the title bar of `Files` (the four squares one) and you will be presented with the grid view.

You can toggle between the settings at will.

Click on the hamburger menu 3 parallel lines), select `Preferences` and scroll down to `Show Thumbnails` and ensure the correct selection is set there.

Comment: This is not the solution on the question: when viewing from USB device. (example: Android phone

Comment: @JulienChau I have amended my answer to make it clear that it refers to 22.04 Desktop version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Graham what you write is correct if working with pictures installed on PC, but not with pictures in a phone connected with USB - see question. I suppose you are working with Nautilus, but even in Nemo it does not work.

Comment: @JulienChau I am on Ubuntu 20.04 with an earlier version of Nautilus. For me, the thumbnail settings are: "Files on this computer only" (this one would indeed exclude the USB), "All files" (this should indeed include previews for the USB), and "Never". OP's screenshot reveals that they had set in preferences: "**Show thumbnails: All files**". Also, the screenshot shows the list view. Switching to thumbnails view would 1.) trigger the image thumbnailer process 2.) resolve the problem. Also: my Nautilus does not show image previews when in list view, even if those previews exist in cache.